# There is mismatch between HTTPS indicated on the server and client

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

This is the warning when I open my phpMyAdmin's login (index) page:

```
There is mismatch between HTTPS indicated on the server and client.
This can lead to non working phpMyAdmin or a security risk.
Please fix your server configuration to indicate HTTPS properly.
```

The error should be caused by a loadbalancer in between my client and phpmyadmin itself. SSL terminates on the loadbalancer so the URL being used (that phpmyadmin receives in request headers, I assume) is https://mydomain/phpmyadmin.

The loadbalancer communicates with phpmyadmin via http, so the URL being used between lb and pma is http://mydomain/phpmyadmin (not https).

I found this very fitting article on github: [Possibility to deactivate SSL connection #170](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/issues/170) which is for Docker containers and describes an env var to be passed to the container called "PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI" to fix the problem.

Which setting would this be in phpmyadmin NON Docker?

Any other solution to my problem is also highly appreciated.

**Sidenote:** Phpmyadmin works fine after the login. You can log in, there are no warnings after the log in and you can perform all interactions without problems. I am just worried about the warning.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have exactly the same setup as you are describing. A front load balancer acts as reverse proxy and also as SSL/TLS terminator. The LB talks in plain http with the backend server where phpMyAdmin is running.

When I upgraded from 4.0.4.1 to 4.9.0.1 I got the same warning appearing at the phpMyAdmin login screen as you. I was able to solve this on the reverse proxy by "faking" the protocol from http to https. In my case my reverse proxy is a Nginx web server and just before I'd pass to the backend server, I added `X-Forwarded-Proto`:

```
 server {
  listen 443;
  server_name my.phpmyadmin.example.com;

[... log and ssl settings ...]

  location / {
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_pass http://backendserver;
  }
}
```

By adding `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;` this tells the backend server that the client to proxy communication happens over https. Without setting this header, phpMyAdmin probably identifies (not sure, just a guess) that it was loaded on a https:// URL yet the communication (between reverse proxy and phpMyAdmin server) happened over http. Therefore it's a correct warning to be shown.

As soon as Nginx was reloaded, the warning disappared from the phpMyAdmin login screen.

Comment: I see, interesting. I will see if I can give this a try (as the loadbalancer is not under my control and most likely not an nginx but some enterprise-monster) but I will let the hoster know and see if we can get that done. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Worp in general a reverse proxy (open source, enterprise, or else) should be capable to add HTTP headers. In this particular case this would be the `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` header.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  This worked like a charm when running PMA on Docker via Nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` would handle both http or https accordingly.